# attaching a function to onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript, still confusing with some syntax about javascript, following is an example:
I want my html display date whenever button clicked

**Question one:**  why first code should be changed to second to make it work?

```
 document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick="displayDate()";
```

.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick=function(){displayDate()};
```

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>click to execute <em>displayDate()</em> 。</p>

<button id="myBtn">PUSH ME !</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick="displayDate()";
function displayDate()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

-----The reason it  confuses me is when we adding script directly into some element, syntax like onclick="changetext(this)" works fine.

**Question 2:** Is there any specific reason why we should differ syntax for this two different cases?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changetext(id)
{
id.innerHTML="Thanks!";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 onclick="changetext(this)">Push me</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The onclick property of a DOM object takes a function as its argument, not a string. In this case you're writing with JavaScript.

The onclick attribute in the HTML is itself a string (as are all XML attributes), but it's treated differently, it gets `eval`ed by the HTML parser.

Note that you don't need a wrapping function.

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick=displayDate;
```